# c++ iterate over base and derived class

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm trying to find a way to get an iterator to work on a list of custom objects and a list of objects derived from that custom object. My, perhaps misguided, goal is to allow me to leave the "production" code and objects intact yet accessible from the "experimental/extended" things that I'm trying out.

Here's a pretty minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::list;

struct comp{
    double x,y;

    void print(){
        cout << "x: " << x << endl;
        cout << "y: " << y << endl;
    }
    comp(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    comp(double X, double Y){
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
    // Standard/Tested Member Functions
};

struct base{
    list<comp> components;
    double known, tested, variables;

    void print_comps(){
        for (list<comp>::iterator it = components.begin(); it != components.end(); ++it){
            // Ideally, this function should work for comp1 and comp1x
            // as inherited in the basex class
            it->print();
        }
    }
    // Standard/Tested Member Functions
};

struct compx : comp{
    double w,z;
    double some, alter, nates;

    void print(){
        cout << "x: " << x << endl;
        cout << "y: " << y << endl;
        cout << "w: " << w << endl;
        cout << "z: " << z << endl;
    }
    compx(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        w = 0;
    }
    compx(double X, double Y, double Z, double W){
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        z = Z;
        w = W;
    }
    // Experimental/Un-tested Member Functions
};

struct basex : base{
    list<compx> components;
    double exper, imen, tal;

    // void print_comps(){} // This should be inherited from base

    // Experimental/Un-tested Member Functions
};

int main(){

    base compilation1;
    compilation1.components.push_back(comp(1,2));
    compilation1.components.push_back(comp(3,4));
    cout << "printing normal struct" << endl;
    compilation1.print_comps();

    cout << endl;

    basex compilation2;
    compilation2.components.push_back(compx(9, 5, 5, 6));
    compilation2.components.push_back(compx(7, 2, 1, 8));
    cout << "printing extended struct" << endl;
    compilation2.print_comps();     // Prints nothing

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Printing via specific iterator" << endl;
    for (list<compx>::iterator it = compilation2.components.begin(); it != compilation2.components.end(); ++it){
        it->print();    // Works as expected.
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Press ENTER to exit." << endl; cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to iterate over both the original class and the extended class in the same functions so I don't clutter the extended class with all the original code. This would allow me to  simply move code from the extended class to the original class as those variables or functions are proven or matured.

Background:

- I'm not married to lists -- any other iterable class would be fine.
- I'm not a developer -- I'm a ChemE trying to make daily tasks a bit easier without breaking what I've already built.
- Branches in a git repository are not a great solution because other non-developer, potentially code-challenged, folks may try to extend this. Getting them to use even one branch would be a miracle.
- I'm using g++ 7.4.0 on Linux (Lubuntu) and 6.3.0 on Windows 7.

**TL;DR:**

Is there a way to get an iterator of `list<parent_object>` to also iterate over `list<child_object>`?

Comment: What is the question? I can only guess: You want it->print() to use the most derived print? Then use virtual functions.

Comment: making print_comps() virtual does not solve the problem; nor does making print() in the base struct virtual. I would like print_comps() to iterate over both the base (comp) and extended (compx) structs.

Comment: The actual function being called within the loop is not important and will most certainly not be "print" in actuality. In a perfect situation, it would only be declared in the base/parent struct and the inherited version would work for the child struct.

Comment: I now understand what you are trying to do. You can store (smart) pointers to base class, not values.

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by having `base` as a template http://cpp.sh/7r2x6a

```
template<typename T>
struct base
{
    list<T> components;
    double known, tested, variables;

    void print_comps(){
        for (auto it = components.begin(); it != components.end(); ++it){
            // Ideally, this function should work for comp1 and comp1x
            // as inherited in the basex class
            it->print();
        }
    }
    // Standard/Tested Member Functions
};
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I can't work out how to get this to also work for the basex struct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with not being able to mix `comp` and `compx` objects together in the same `list`, then you can use a templated function to avoid duplicate code.

For example, you can do the following in your `struct base`:

```
struct base{
   list<comp> components;
   double known, tested, variables;

   void print_comps() {print_comps_aux<comp>(components);}

   protected:
      template <typename CompType> void print_comps_aux(list<CompType> & compsArg)
      {
         for (typename list<CompType>::iterator it = compsArg.begin(); it != compsArg.end(); ++it){
            it->print();
         }
      }

   // Standard/Tested Member Functions
};
```

... and then in your `struct basex` you can just have this:

```
[...]

void print_comps() {print_comps_aux<compx>(components);}
```